# Build formula with Filter in VBA and insert in to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following formula that I'd like to insert in to a specific cell using vba. The code I have is as follows:

```
Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
Set ThisSheet = ActiveSheet
ThisSheet.Range("H40").Formula = "=FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Project Code Name]=B2), {1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})"
```

It does insert the formula but it inserts an @ symbol at the start, as follows:

`=@FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Project Code Name]=B2), {1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})`

If I manually delete the @ symbol the formula works fine. Is there a way to adjust the vba code for inserting the formula to exclude the @ symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Formula2 there is no @ symbol:

`ThisSheet.Range("H40").Formula2 = "=FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Project Code Name]=B2), {1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0})"`